# Xamarin Forms Update ListView on WillEnterForeground

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Objective**

Update a Xamarin.Forms ListView when the iOS Application Enters the foreground

**Approach**

The closes example I have seen is found in the monotouch samples

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/SimpleBackgroundFetch/SimpleBackgroundFetch/AppDelegate.cs

```
public override void PerformFetch (UIApplication application, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            UINavigationController navigationController = Window.RootViewController as UINavigationController;
            UIViewController topViewController = navigationController.TopViewController;
            if (topViewController is RootViewController) {
                (topViewController as RootViewController).InsertNewObjectForFetch (completionHandler);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber++;
            } else
                completionHandler (UIBackgroundFetchResult.Failed);
        }
```

This is using PerformFetch but the WillEnterForegroundMethod will accomplish what I am trying to do.

**Problem**

The problem is I am using a Xamarin.Form Page and don't know how to get access to the Page or the Pages' ViewModel from the App Delegate Class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could register the ViewModel with an IoC container when you set it as the BindingContext for the View and then get it using that.

If you're using MVVMLight, SimpleIoC is included in that package.